# PHP MSSQL (Transact-SQL) - parameterized query with IN clause and multiple values in array

Tags: php, sql-server, t-sql, parameterized

I am stuck with a piece of PHP code (PHP 5) where I am running an SQL query (Transact SQL).

The Code (which is not working):

```
$query = "
  UPDATE my_table
  SET my_column = 'some_value'
  WHERE my_id IN (?);" // does not work :-(
sqlsrv_query($my_connection, $query, array('abc', 'def', 'ghi')); // does not work :-(
```

What I am trying to do: Update my_table in my_column for rows with my_id equal to abc, def and ghi.

However, when I write the same SQL query with no parameters (this works):

```
$query = "
  UPDATE my_table
  SET my_column = 'some_value'
  WHERE my_id IN ('abc', 'def', 'ghi');" // works :-)
sqlsrv_query($my_connection, $query); // works :-)
```

I've tried to execute the sqlsrv_query command like this

```
sqlsrv_query($my_connection, $query, array('abc', 'def', 'ghi'));
```

and like this

```
sqlsrv_query($my_connection, $query, array(array('abc', 'def', 'ghi')));
```

and like this

```
sqlsrv_query($my_connection, $query, 'abc', 'def', 'ghi');
```

None of them work.

Can someone please help me? I've had a good read on the manual. And writing the SQL like this

```
... WHERE my_id IN (?,?,?)...
```

is not an option since my array will contain a variable amount of values!

Thank you!

Comment: `$query = "UPDATE ... WHERE my_id IN (" . implode(',', array_fill(0, count($ids), '?')) . ")";` Easily handles multiple bound parameters. Be weary of the maximum limit.

Comment: Hi Colin, thank you for your answer! By imploding my array of ids - do I still get an SQL-injection safe "parameterized query" out of your solution? Does not look like it to me (maybe I'm wrong) - can you please explain?! Thank you!

Comment: I'm not imploding your array of IDs. I'm creating a string of question marks (placeholders) separated by commas. You still get all the benefits of bound parameters if you bind as usual!

Comment: aaaah, I've just now tried it, and it works! Thank you very much! As I will in no case have more than 100 ids, your solution will work (maximum limit will not be breached). I had hoped to get a solution with ONE ? and SQL being smart enough to convert my array() to the apropriate string needed to fill the IN()... Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1):

I just handled the same problem, only in Visual Studio. First I created a string of parameters to add into the SQL statement. You only have to deal with question marks (?), so much of what I did is more than you need:

```
string[] inClause = new string[keywordTerms.Length];

for (int i = 0; i < keywordTerms.Length; i++)
    inClause[i] = ":keyword" + i.ToString("00");
```

Then when creating my select, I put the following in:

```
sqlStatement += "WHERE kw.keyword IN (" + String.Join(", ", inClause) + ")"
```

Finally, I added the parameters in this code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < keywordTerms.Length; i++)
    cmd.Parameters.Add(inClause[i], OracleDbType.Varchar2, 20, "keyword").Value = keywordTerms[i];
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hi ESDictor! Thank you very much! That helps, as it is basically the same solution as Colin has pointed out. Basically you are adding the same number of ":keyword" placeholders in your SQL statement which you later fill by adding the parameters to the code. I was hoping to find a solution with only ONE ":keyword" in my SQL statement and was hoping that MSSQL is smart enough to popluate that ONE :keyword with multiple values! But hey, your solution works, too! Thanks :-)

Comment: I know how you feel, but after a lot of searching I came up with this approach, and it works as well as I could hope. Good luck with it!

Answer (score 1):

The answer to my question was given by Colin and ESDictor:

```
$params = array('abc', 'def', 'ghi');
$query = "
  UPDATE my_table
  SET my_column = 'some_value'
  WHERE my_id IN (" . implode(',', array_fill(0, count($params), '?')) . ");" // works like a charm
sqlsrv_query($my_connection, $query, $params);
```

Thank you guys! I'd like to upvote your answer, Colin, in particular (but cannot since you 'just' commented. ESDictors answer is basically the same!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$params = array('abc', 'def', 'ghi'); //assume it dinamic
$query = "
UPDATE my_table
SET my_column = 'some_value'
WHERE my_id IN (";
$inside = "";
foreach ($params as $key => $value) {

$inside = $inside."?,";
}

$inside = trim ($inside,",");
$query = $query.$inside.");";

sqlsrv_query($my_connection, $query, $params);
```

PS: Now the code can handle a dinamic array XD

Saludos ;)

Comment: Hi Robert, thank you very much for your help! I know, this works - but does not work if my params array holds a dynamically changing amount of keys (i.e.: if $params = array('abc', 'def'); I'd have to change the ? to (?,?);"... ;)

Comment: Robert, thank you for your help - I've figured it out already (see my summary of Colins and ESDictors answers above).